# JabRef and legal citations

Tags: jabref

I've just started using JabRef, but I need to use it for quite a few legal citations. I'm wondering how to manage two things:

1. create entries for opinions of authorities and judgments, etc.

1.1 or, how to use something like jurabib

2. how do I use add a citation style like: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/oscola

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to JabRef!
JabRef supports by default the standard biblatex entry types. However, it's possible to create custom entry types with different fields.

In the end it comes down to what citation style in latex you are using and what fields are supported. 
In doubt, you can always use the Mis entry type.

For the second question, since JabRef 4.x, JabRef added support for [Citation Style Language](https://citationstyles.org/)  in the entry preview. 
There are various styles available